# Why isn't there a "base" design package in adminhtml?

Tags: design, design-packages

Why isn't there a `/design/adminhtml/base` and `/skin/adminhtml/base`? Sine CE 1.4 and EE 1.8 the frontend section uses `/design/base` now instead of `/design/default` as the final fallback area. It seems inconsistent that adminhtml would still use `/design/adminhtml/default` instead of having been refactored to be called `/design/adminhtml/base`.

Just curious really.

Answer (score 3):

I think it simply wasn't high up on the priority list as admin customisations would rarely require multiple level of fallbacks (more important for frontend, with the latest releases even supporting infinite fallbacks).

If you like you can rename
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default` to 
`app/design/adminhtml/base/default`
and
`skin/adminhtml/default/default` to  `skin/adminhtml/base/default` and will actually work since the fallback code is used across both frontend and backend.